# Use Bias with apachesolr module

Tags: search

I want to use Apache Solr in my site build with Drupal7.
The server is UP, simples searches are working but I can't boost a field with bias.

For example, I boosted the title (or label in the administration page), giving him a 5 in the select field.

After re-index the node, I searched and the order of the result still the same.

I tried to create a little module with apachesolr's hook to watch the document it send to solr server.

`hook_apachesolr_index_documents_alter()`:

```
[_fieldBoosts:protected] => Array
(
[id] => 
[site] => 
[hash] => 
[entity_id] => 
[entity_type] => 
[bundle] => 
[bundle_name] => 
[path] => 
[url] => 
[language] => 
[path_alias] => 
[label] => 
[content] => 
[teaser] => 
[ss_name] => 
[tos_name] => 
[ss_name_formatted] => 
[tos_name_formatted] => 
[is_uid] => 
[bs_status] => 
[bs_sticky] => 
[bs_promote] => 
[is_tnid] => 
[bs_translate] => 
[ss_language] => 
[ds_created] => 
[ds_changed] => 
[ds_last_comment_or_change] => 
[is_comment_count] => 
[type_name] => 
[created] => 
[changed] => 
[last_comment_or_change] => 
[comment_count] => 
[name] => 
[tos_content_extra] => 
[access__all] => 
)
```

All the data are empty.

This is a screenshot of my module setting page.

[screenshot http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/7984/drupalsolrconf.png](http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/7984/drupalsolrconf.png)

Answer (score 2):

To verify the boost values are included in your queries, tail the Solr `request.log` file.  You'll see things like `&qf=label%5E5.0` (%5e is a caret ^, which marks the boost value).

Another useful trick for optimizing the scores is to include the score in your themed results output.  You may find the boosts are affecting the scores, but aren't high enough to substantially change the ranking.  This can be added with a small hook:

```
function hook_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  if (user_access('administer search')) {
    $variables['title_suffix'] = '<code>[score: ' . $variables['result']['score'] . ']</code>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The settings page you are referring to controls query-time boosts, not index-time boosts. So perhaps you can find the effective boosts better in a query-modifying hook.

Comment: This also means that you do not need to reïndex content after changing the bias settings!